# How do I create a new ActionResult in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionresult

If I have MVC controller that is using something like,

```
public ActionResult Index()
{

return View();
}

public ActionResult Display()
{

return View();
}
```

When I run something like this it does not seem to recognize the action for "Display", suppose I use an action link in razor for example,

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display", "Display")
```

For what whatever reason this is not routing to the new action result I created, "Display", when ActionLink is clicked. What is the proper way to do this? Do I need a separate controller for this new action?

Comment: Do you have any custom routes defined (for example in route config)?

Comment: What's the controller name?

Comment: Is the view in the same folder name as the controller or in shared?

Comment: Assume that your controller is called HomeController, then if you create a view called /View/Home/Display.cshtml, it should work. If it doesn't, then what does your /App_Start/RouteConfig.cs file look like? Did you modify it? Also, are you sure your view (Display.cshtml) is valid? If in doubt, you might try replacing your current version with something very simple that you know works.

Comment: No, I using the default routes.

Comment: The controller name is HomeController.

Answer (score 0):

For your example:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display", "Display")
```

The first parameter is your linkText and the second parameter is the actionName. You really should add a third parameter for your controllerName. So, for example, this:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Display", "Display", "Home")
```

Would mean "Display" is shown as your link text, and the link would navigate to the HomeController and call the Display action method as desired.

In my example above, the resulting HTML source would look like this:

```
<a href="/Display">Display</a>
```

("/Home" is not shown as it is implied to be to top level depending on default routing configuration)

Clear?